# Authentification with client info

Tags: uber-api

is it possible in uber delivery to use the uber user information to authenticate and bill.
I do not wish to manage the delivery but would like to offer the option for regular uber user to get a delivery using their own account and billed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the three legged oauth guide for the deliveries api: https://developer.uber.com/docs/deliveries/guides/three-legged-oauth